# Show all items in <li>

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So i have a list with over 1000 items in it and i display it with custom made Bootstrap dropdown list which uses

```
<ul ng-repeat="items in list"> 
<li> 
{{items}}
</li> 
</ul>
```

now it only shows items to the end of my screen, about a 100 items.

I tried adding overflow:auto but it didnt help.

```
 //not working
<ul ng-repeat="items in list" style="overflow:auto"> 
    <li> 
    {{items}}
    </li> 
    </ul>
```

any other way to add the scroll bar so i can scroll my 1000 items ?

Comment: Give it a fixed height and add `overflow-y:auto` ?

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, thats what i did.. working now..

Comment: @Orom shouldn't you ng-repeat be on your li item ? you'r making 100 ul with on ly 1 li element on each with that code

Answer (score 2):

```
 max-height: 400px;overflow: hidden;overflow-y: auto;"
```

fixed it by adding these to my css.

Comment: why applied both **overflow: hidden;overflow-y: auto;** can you explain this.?